# How to get parameters name and value in RequestHandler of JAX-RS based Service in CXF

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am creating a JAX-RS based web service in CXF and I want to get the parameters passed to the method in the `RequestHandler` registered as a `<jaxrs:provider>`.

I want the parameter name and corresponding value in the handler and here is my code:

```
public class SampleRequestHandler implements RequestHandler {

@Override
public Response handleRequest(Message arg0, ClassResourceInfo arg1) {
    OperationResourceInfo resourceInfo = arg0.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
    String name = resourceInfo.getMethodToInvoke().getName();

    return null;
    }
}
```

My JAX-RS based service:

```
@Service("bookService")
@Path("/bookstore")
public class BookStore {

    @POST
    @Path("/books")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    @Consumes({ "application/xml" })
    public Book addBook(Book book) {
        return book;
    }

}
```

and my `beans.xml` where I have registered the handler and restful service:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.cxf.jaxrs.service"/>

<bean id="sampleHandler" class="com.tutorial.cxf.jaxrs.interceptors.SampleRequestHandler"/>
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bookService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="sampleHandler"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Anybody already manage this case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to take the method with:

```
List<Parameter> params = ori.getParameters();
```

It only returns the parameter's name (the one declared in the method) but not the values.

The official [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html#JAX-RSFilters-OverridingrequestURI,queryandheaders) shows only a little about it, but as explained you can always take the QUERY_STRING value of the message and parse it.

You can do something like this in your handler/filter:

```
String queryString = (String) arg0.get(Message.QUERY_STRING);
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryMap = JAXRSUtils.getStructuredParams(queryString, "&", false, false);
```

and after loop over the queryMap collection. The map will contains all  of your query parameters, even those who are not declared in the Rest method of your BookStore class.